# Why does custom WinForms control not adhere to properties set in constructor when drawn?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a custom text box control that inherits from `System.Windows.Forms.TextBox`.

Basically I set it up so that it automatically checks whether the value entered is a number every time the text changes. Sample code:

```
public class MyTextBox : TextBox {

    public MyTextBox() : base() {
        base.TextChanged += MyTextBox_TextChanged;
        base.BackColor = Color.White;
        base.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    }

    private void MyTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        try {
            int.Parse(base.Text);
            base.BackColor = Color.White;
            base.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        } catch(FormatException) {
            base.BackColor = Color.Red;
            base.ForeColor = Color.White;
        }
    }
}
```

As indicated above, I have the default background and foreground to `White` and `Black` respectively, but the WinForms designer draws the component as having a red background, and it comes up that way when I launch the program as well. When I start typing numbers in, however, it does change back to black/white and otherwise behaves as expected.

But why does the control seem to override the properties I set in the constructor? When the control is initially drawn, the text isn't changed... or is it?

Comment: Did you add this code after dropping the control on a form, or before?

Comment: Might've been after, but when I make changes I always rebuild the solution, still doesn't seem to correct it

Comment: When you dropped the control on the form, the form designer saved the current colors to the form designer code. Changes you do in the constructor of the control to the same properties are overwritten immediately by the form that owns the control. You should remove and drop the control again and see if that helps. Rebuilding does not help with this problem. You can also go to the .Designer.cs file for the form and remove the offending lines but it is safer to remove and drop the control again after changing its code like this.

Comment: Still doesn't work, I do see that the Designer.cs is overwriting the color settings, but why? The code to change the color is only supposed to run when the text changes. Does the text "change" when the control is dropped on the form?

Comment: Yes, the current text of the control is also saved and set back to the control in the form designer code. Since the initial text of a textbox is an empty string, which cannot be parsed, you get the red color.

Comment: Figured... that's annoying. Well, I just added a check to the event handler to test for empty string/length 0, so now it works fine. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I also wouldn't use `try`...`catch` here. Use `int.TryParse()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you dropped the control onto the form, its current properties are saved by the form designer.

This includes things like:

- ForeColor
- BackColor
- Text

When you construct the form, these properties are set back to the control.

In the constructor of your control you set up the background color to be white, but you don't change the text, so the text property stays as an empty string.

This empty string cannot be parsed so now we have two possible scenarios:

- BackColor is set by the form designer code before Text, in which case the event handler for TextChanged wins. Since the text is an empty string, which cannot be parsed, the background color turns red immediately though it was white for a short while
- The opposite happens, Text is set, parse fails, background color is set to red, and then the form designer sets back the saved background color to white.

Control properties are set in alphabetical order (if I'm not mistaken) so the first scenario is the one you see.

In short, you got a couple of ways to handle this:

- Decide if an empty string is legal, though possibly with some default value (null perhaps?)
- Make sure the constructor of your control assigns it a text that is a legal parsable integer value (`0` comes to mind)